# Scope issue within JavaScript Object literal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm actually new to programming and this community. Currently I'm working on a code that facing a scope issue with object literals. can anyone help me with this?

```
var obj = {
   value: 3,
   print:()=>console.log(value)
}

obj.print();
```

When we are using non arrow functions it is working. I can only use arrow functions here.

Comment: Can you include errors?

Comment: Even a regular function would not work here

Comment: you need `this.value` for non-arrow function

Comment: @Marios that won't work because the code uses a `=>` function

Comment: @Pointy yeah I meant the regular function as he said, I should have made it clear

Comment: @Marios It only prints undefined if we use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the `this` keyword to reference the object, but then you would have use a regular function instead of an arrow function.

```js
const obj = {
  value: 3,
  print() {
    console.log(this.value)
  },
};

obj.print();
```

Or you can reference the object directly (better to use previous approach).

```js
const obj = {
  value: 3,
  print: () => console.log(obj.value),
};

obj.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to use the reference if you only want to use the arrow functions.

```
var obj = {
   value: 3,
   print:()=>console.log(obj.value)
}

obj.print();
```